# Efficiently SELECTing items with a common foreign key and various other values

Tags: sql

I feel I may have worked myself into a corner, but I'm 270 million rows in and would rather not start over. :)

I have a table, Positions, that has the following relevant columns:

- id: Position ID
- event_id: Foreign key for events
- position: Actual position of this field
- word_id: foreign key to unique words

I'm trying to figure out a way to efficiently do a query using ANSI SQL that amounts to an inner join, but I'm stumped.  Here's what I need to find:

I am interested in all distinct values of event_id where a set of positions (related by the event_id) contain a set of words (related by word_id).

Have I put myself in a corner?  I feel like I need another join table that ties words directly to events in order to do this efficiently.

Positions Schema:

```
                                     Table "public.positions"
   Column   |            Type             |                       Modifiers                        
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('positions_id_seq'::regclass)
 word_id    | integer                     | 
 position   | integer                     | 
 event_id   | integer                     | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
    "positions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_words" btree (word_id)
    "index_positions_on_event_id" btree (event_id)
    "index_positions_on_word_id" btree (word_id)
```

Comment: Can you post your actual schema?

Comment: You also need to tell us which DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle? ("*SQL*" is not the name of a database product, it's a query language)

Comment: Postgresql but I'm looking for an ANSI sql answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by creating another join table, events_words, that's used to track which words appear in which events.  This allows for a far more efficient inner join, though inner joins tend to be super messy in my opinion:

```
select distinct a.event_id from events_words as a inner join events_words as b on a.event_id=b.event_id and b.word_id=1 inner join events_words as c on a.event_id=c.event_id and c.word_id=15;
```

Works super and query time is down from 45 seconds+ to < 1 second.